# Problem with return values and "__main__"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve hackerrank "find a string". this is code :

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    d = 0 
    e = 0
    z= []
    hasil = 0
    while d != int(len(string)-1):
        z.append(string[d])
        d+=1   
        z.append(string[d])
    if d < int(len(string)-1):
        d+=1
        z.append(string[d]) 
        asd = ''.join(z)
        if sub_string==asd:
            e+=1 
        else:
            pass
        z.clear()
        d-=1 
    return e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()

    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

output for my code is 0 although the correct one is 2. but if i write the code without using function and '**main**: with this code

```
s = input().strip()
a = input().strip()
d = 0 
e = 0
z= []

while d != int(len(s)-1):
    z.append(s[d])
    d+=1   
    z.append(s[d])
    if d < int(len(s)-1):
        d+=1
        z.append(s[d]) 
        asd = ''.join(z)
        if a==asd:
            e+=1 
        else:
            pass
        z.clear()
        d-=1 
    elif d == int(len(s)-1): 
        print(e)
```

this code get the correct output. I've tried with change the return value or just print in function but still don't worked.

Comment: the output is 2 if i input string = ABCDCDC and sub_string = CDC

Comment: These 2 pieces of code are not equivalent (at least if it's not a copy-paste typo) so that souldn't be surprising. In the second code all of it is under the `while`. In the first one the first `if` is **outside** the `while`